# Windows App uses SharpSVN - need to migrate server to linux SVN server - will it still work?

Tags: linux, windows, winforms, sharpsvn

Our Windows Forms application uses SharpSVN for SVN file checkouts, updates, and commits as well as other things. The current SVN server is also Windows but it is being EOL'd and now the company only supports SVN on Linux. Does it matter to SharpSVN whether SVN is on a Linux or Windows server?

Thanks,
Judie

Answer (score 0):

As long as the SharpSvn binaries are used on Windows, this should work. SharpSvn can connect to any Subversion repository regardless on which platform it is hosted.

Moving the repository to a different server shouldn't matter.

Using the SharpSvn based application on Linux would be a different story, as SharpSvn doesn't work on Mono/Linux or Mono/MacOS.